# OR operator in Postman Response Tests

Tags: postman

I have the following assertion in my postman script test, but for some reason the tests are failing when one of the following is missing: Lease, Finance, or cash in my response body. Is the "||" not the OR operator?

```
tests["Deal Type"] = responseBody.has("Lease" || "Finance" || "Cash");
```

Answer (score 13):

It should be something like:

```
pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.be.oneOf([201,202]);
```

Answer (score 6):

According to the [postman docs](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_examples) the correct syntax would be

```
tests["Deal Type"] = responseBody.has("Lease") || responseBody.has("Finance") || responseBody.has("Cash");
```

Comment: It seem like this syntax is deprecated by now (according to the [docs](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/test-examples/)).
Is there a way to use AND / OR operations for different parts of the response with the new syntax?
Example in old syntax:

`tests[either 201 or (content-type application/json and body check)"] = responseCode.code === 201 || (postman.getResponseHeader("Content-Type") === "application/json" && responseBody.has("example_text"))`

Answer (score 6):

Write it is like this..

```
pm.expect(pm.response.data[0].DealType).to.be.oneOf(['Lease', 'Finance','Cash']);
```